# How to use @Valid @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Can someone please suggest and provide example on how to use the @Valid annotation for @RequestHeader Map<String, String> fields in spring boot

Comment: You don't, it is only supported for `@ModelAttributes` and `@RequestBody`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write class like below:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Map;

@Validated
public class MyHeaders {
public Map<String, String> getHeaders(@Valid @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
return headers;
}
}
```

below is my controller class:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

private final MyHeaders myHeaders;

public MyController(MyHeaders myHeaders) {
this.myHeaders = myHeaders;
}
@GetMapping("/")
public String hello() {
    Map<String, String> headers = myHeaders.getHeaders();
    // Do something with the headers
    return "Hello";
}
}
```

Comment: In the swagger-ui, how can I display these header map parameters?

Comment: @ApiOperation(value = "/hello", notes = "This is an example method.")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Content-Type", value = "The Content-Type header value", dataType = "string", paramType = "header", required = true),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "The Authorization header value", dataType = "string", paramType = "header", required = true)
})
@PostMapping("/hello")
public ResponseEntity<String> exampleMethod(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
    <!-- Add Your Code here -->
}

Comment: Thank you, can we pass name and value here from a list of message properties, i dont want to hard code the names.  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "The Authorization header value", dataType = "string",

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can pass the value and name from list of message property.
First you can define the message properties in "application.properties" file.

```
header.authorization.name=Authorization
header.authorization.value=<your_value>
header.authorization.dataType=string
```

And next you can use @Value annotation in your controller class like below:

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorld{
    
    @Value("${header.authorization.name}")
    private String authorizationHeaderName;

    @Value("${header.authorization.value}")
    private String authorizationHeaderValue;

    @Value("${header.authorization.dataType}")
    private String authorizationHeaderdataType;

    @PostMapping(value = "/getmessage")
    @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(name = ${header.authorization.name}", value = "${header.authorization.value}", dataType = 
 ${header.authorization.dataType}", paramType = "header")
    })
    public responseEntity<?> getMessage(){
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok("HelloWorld");

    }
    
}
```